# Turn on fast startup - "Restart isn't affected"

Tags: windows, windows-10

On the Control Panel option for turning on fast startup, it says:

> Restart isn't affected.

Does this mean that a restart is always a "fast startup" or that it is NOT one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full line is:

> This helps start your PC faster after shutdown. Restart isn't affected.

The first sentence is telling you the option affects the system after being powered on from a *shutdown*.  A *restart* is not a system shutdown, it's a reboot.

So, as it says, the option will not affect Restarts.

Perhaps check out this other SU question for more information relating to Shutdowns vs. Restarts: [Difference between shutting down and turning on vs. restart in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/508050/difference-between-shutting-down-and-turning-on-vs-restart-in-windows-8)

Comment: Just to make sure: You're saying that a restart will never use the fast hibernation-based startup. Correct?

Comment: Correct, that is what I'm saying. :)

Comment: @ispiro - A reboot is a power state supported by the CPU.  Hibernate also is a state supported by the CPU.  The two modes are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

Restart shuts everything down and then restarts the computer. With fast startup, when you select Shut Down, your applications are shut down and then the Windows processes are hibernated. On start up the Windows processes are resumed.

Comment: Shutdown + Fast Startup is pretty much same as logout + login, but shutdown + fast startup is slower.