# Shutdown+TurnOn vs Restart - Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop, shutdown

I'm having a strange problem with Windows 10 and remote access through a VPN (NeoRouter).

I am accessing a Win10 PC remotely. If I "restart" the PC then the PC shows up in the NeoRouter VPN as being on-line and active in the VPN **but** I cannot ping the VPN address (10.0.0.xx) and cannot connect remotely. If I have someone on-site shutdown the PC normally from within Win10 and then turn on the PC 5 seconds later the PC shows up in the VPN **and** I can ping it and access it directly. As part of the troubleshooting I turned off hibernation, which is supposed to disable Fast Startup - that made no difference (although some people found having it enabled caused problems).

If the behavior was the same regardless of how I rebooted (Shutdown+TurnOn vs Restart) then I'd suspect the VPN settings were somehow at fault. But, because my remote access depends on the method of startup I suspect it is something in Win10.

This question [Difference between shutting down and turning on vs. restart in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/508050/difference-between-shutting-down-and-turning-on-vs-restart-in-windows-8) would be helpful except that it suggests I should be experiencing behavior opposite to what I see. If Shutdown+TurnOn simply restores the previous settings (which the Win8 question says is true) then that should not restore my remote access **but it does**; and, if Restart does a complete shutdown and cold reboot then that should reset everything from scratch and reset my access **but it doesn't**.

One further clue - I can access the shared hard drive of the un-pingable PC from another PC (via remote access) on the same local network (connected through a router) so I know the PC is active and working on the local network even though it is not pingable through the VPN.

Comment: So a restart of the remote PC causes it to be seen but not accessible and a shutdown and re-power allows it back to normal access? Odd indeed .. Can you test a hard reset? That is, turn off the machine by holding the power button. If after turning it on you experience the same thing as a reboot, that might hint that whatever VPN/RD service is running isn't properly shutting down/restarting/etc. ..?

Comment: Just trying to help: are you 100% sure of your assumption? Can you perhaps re-test it? Once may have just been a co-incidence. Twice would confirm it.

Comment: @txtechhelp - I'll give that a try when I can get someone to the site. So far, all the Restarts were remote and all the Shutdown+TurnOns were through Win10 itself.

Comment: @RichardWoolf - I had the same thought so I tried at least 5-7 times and got the same result each time. If it is coincidence it is a **highly** unlikely one.